# Laravel 5 set route conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I want to get specific route only based on the condition. I currently tried Session but it doesn't work with routes. So anyone here might want to help if there's simpe way to this.

```
if(\Session::get('quiz_type') == 'quiz'){
    Route::resource('quizzes.questions', 'QuestionsController');
}else{
    Route::resource('surveys.questions', 'QuestionsController');
}
```

I want that certain route Quiz only if I passed and meet a certain condtion. Else I want to call on different route.

Comment: `Route::resource` isn't suppose to work like that. Basically it will return the same routes just with a different string representation

Comment: Hi assuming I will not use Route::resource, is it possible to use condition like the sample above?

Comment: depends on how do you set up the `quiz_type`, is it a url parameter, a cookie or a session. if its a session it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly Session start only after laravel has already parsed the routes file, this is why your code doesn't work as you expect.